# getting error: more than one instance of AVPlayer

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer

When I hit autoplay button twice or after one play, I hit stop button and then hit autoplay again, I get this error: An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer.

```
var queue: AVQueuePlayer!
var items : [AVPlayerItem] = []

    @IBAction func autoplay(_ sender: Any) {
    player.stop() // AVAudioPlayer
    for number in myIndex...arr.count {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: String(number), withExtension: "mp3")!
        items.append(AVPlayerItem(url: url))

    }
     queue = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
    queue.play()
    queue.rate = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey:"playSpeed")
      }

    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
    player.stop()
    if items.isEmpty {
    }
    else{
    queue.pause()
    queue.removeAllItems()
    }
}
```

Comment: you are running all items simultaneously, any reason?

Comment: sorry but you mean, in sequence? my app plays lots of mp3 files. I want my users to listen to all the files automatically by just clicking on one button.

Comment: but way is wrong. you played all same time. you should implement when one finish then another will start.